# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. after Login ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, cookies

I Recently Changed My Hosting Server,
I Randomly Get This Error Message after Login:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

and when I Delete The related cookies in Browser The Site Loads Again.

I Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2

startup.cs Code:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(43200);
            });
```

and login Part Code:

```
            User user = await _userService.LoginUserAsync(login.Email, login.Password);
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.UserID.ToString())
            };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var pricipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                IsPersistent = login.RememberMe
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(pricipal, properties);
```

I never had same problem on my previous Hosting Plan.

Is This Problem  Related to Host Settings?

Comment: `I Recently Changed My Hosting Server` What was the original hosting server and what is it now? Could you share more details that can reproduce the issue step by step?

Comment: Both are Shared Hosting Plans on Windows Server
in Plesk Tools>Failed Request Tracing ,I've found something related to Module:ModSecurity IIS that blocking Request.
Could misconfiguration of this Module Cause this 403 Error?

Comment: This post might help you, take a look at https://windowswebhostingreview.com/troubleshoot-403-error-when-publishing-asp-net-core/. Basically it was caused that you haven't setup your own default page correctly.